# Difference between passing parameters in URL vs as a param object in angular js

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am trying to understand the difference between two rest calls .

One with params object like below -

```
$http({
        url : 'rest/getAllData',
        method : "GET",
        params : {
            A: $scope.A,
            B: $scope.B
}
```

And second in URL -

```
 var win = window.open('rest/getAllData/?A=' + $scope.A+ '&B=' + $scope.B );
```

Problem is in my first rest call , the date time which I getting from angular calendar is in the format

```
1989-12-31T00:00:00.000Z
```

But on second call I am getting format as

```
Sun Apr 30 2017 00:00:00 GMT 0530 (India Standard Time).
```

Can anyone please explain why is this happening ? Also , is there a way to use params object in `windows.open()` itself ?

Update -

Understood that URL by default invokes `toString()` method . That is the reason for the format change . 
Is there a way I can pass date object in `windows.open()` function??

**Answer-**

using `toISOString()` solved my problem . Thanks Claies

Comment: are you saying that `$scope.A` or `$scope.B` (or maybe both) is a `Date` object, and you are wondering why sending it as a `Date` object in `params` is different than sending it as a `String` in a URL call?  JavaScript will automatically invoke the `toString()` method in the second instance... https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_date.asp

Comment: Got it .. Is there any way I can pass date object in windows.open() function?

Comment: no, there is not.  `window.open` takes a string argument for the page to be opened, it does not allow changing the headers or allow access to the request body.

Comment: Any work around??

Comment: don't use `window.open`.  Angular is a Single Page Application framework, using window.open is inherently creating a new page, and thus a new application.  It's use is generally not "The Angular Way"...

Comment: Beyond that, you appear to want the `ISOString` format.  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp.  do something like `$scope.AISO = $scope.A.toISOString()`, then `var win = window.open('rest/getAllData/?A=' + $scope.AISO + '&B=' + $scope.B );`

Comment: It works when I am selecting the date from calendar . but when I am setting $scope.A value like $scope.A ="1989-12-31T00:00:00.000Z" in JS . It says $scope.A.toISOString() is not a function . Why is it so ??

Comment: that's a string, not a `Date`....  if you are already setting it to a string, then you don't need to convert it.

Comment: Thanks Claies . It works . I just converted the string to date using new Date() .